# Change Ubuntu Interface in VM Esxi Client

Tags: 12.04, server, interface

i just got my first job and i need to work on our server. our server has VMWare Esxi V5.5 which has 3 vm's. Each vm has an outdated Ubuntu OS in Command Line. although i figured out how to access it through root access. I would like to switch interface into a GUI for me to learn more about it easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that if you ask me.

Nevertheless `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` as root (or with sudo) should install an xfce desktop. For alternatives you can install lubuntu-desktop (lxde), ubuntu-desktop (unity) or kubuntu-desktop (kde) as well.

If you would start under me and would pull that, you would be in trouble. You can (and should) learn on your desktop and you'll need to learn to rely on the command line for the job.

Last but not least, ubuntu 12.04 isn't outdated yet, it is still supported with updates until April 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The official docs are on [ubuntu.com/ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI).

The answer is to use this commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
```